# How to pull new branch and set up tracking simultaneously?

Tags: git

Suppose that a new branch `NEW` has just appeared in a remote repo.  Is there a `git` command to create a tracking branch for `NEW`, and simultaneously pull it (specifically) from the remote repo?  (By the "specifically" bit I mean pull only the branch `NEW`.)

FWIW: I'm using version 1.7.6.

EDIT: desired scenario
(before)

```
% git branch -a
  bar
  baz
  foo
* master
  remotes/somerepo/bar
  remotes/somerepo/baz
  remotes/somerepo/foo
  remotes/somerepo/master
```

(after)

```
% git branch -a
  bar
  baz
  foo
* master
  NEW
  remotes/somerepo/bar
  remotes/somerepo/baz
  remotes/somerepo/foo
  remotes/somerepo/master
  remotes/somerepo/NEW
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
git branch NEW somerepo/NEW
```

This will create local branch `NEW`, set up to track remote branch `NEW` from `somerepo`.

The thing about `git pull` is that it's a combo of `git fetch` and `get merge`. Since `git merge` can only work on the current branch, you cannot use `git pull` for this purpose. If you want to fetch a specific branch and create a local branch to track it, you have to use the commands:

```
git fetch remote branchname
git branch branchname remote/branchname
```

In older versions of Git, the `git fetch remote branch` might not create `.git/refs/remotes/remote/branchname` correctly. I tested this works as of version 1.8.4, but it doesn't work as of version 1.7.10.4. If it doesn't work with your version, you have to use this more verbose syntax:

```
git fetch remote branchname:remotes/remote/branchname
```

Or if you don't mind fetching all the branches, you could do simply `git fetch remote`.

Comment: If I try the `git fetch`-`git branch` sequence at the end of your post, the `git branch` command fails with `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'remote/branch'`  Of course, I did not actually use `remote` for the name of the remote, nor `branch` for the name of the branch.  In any case, the first command succeeds, so the `remote` parameter seems to be OK.

Comment: As I said, the `fetch` succeeded, which rules out the possibility you describe.

Comment: please see the answer I just posted (FWIW); it shows something that *did* work for me (which may give a clue regarding the discrepancy we're seeing)

Comment: Well, the `--track` is not the *only* difference; the `fetch` command is substantially different.  When I tried your version I did `git fetch ORIGIN NEW`, rather than `git fetch ORIGIN NEW:remotes/ORIGIN/NEW`.  (The latter, BTW, created a file `.git/refs/remotes/ORIGIN/NEW`.)

Comment: ...it creates `.git/refs/remotes/ORIGIN/NEW`.  This is reproducible.

Comment: @kjo I see. I did some more tests with old Git and I could reproduce the behavior you see. Yes, the fetch is not so easy as in my first answer, but the second command should work without `--track`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

This is probably what you want:

```
git checkout -tb NEW somerepo/NEW
```

Comment: `git branch -u remote/NEW` will set the *current branch* to track `remote/NEW`, which is not what the OP wants. `git branch -u remote/NEW NEW` will set `NEW` to track `remote/NEW`, but `NEW` must already exist for this, if it doesn't exist yet you'll get an error

Comment: `git checkout -tb` will also checkout the branch, which is not what the OP wants.